# Codeigniter And Mysql Procedure in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, stored-procedures

How Do I Use ?

My Procedure Library

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Procedure
    {
        var   $CI; 
        public  $result  = NULL; // Dönen Değer Değişkeni

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->CI = & get_instance();

        }

        public function query($sql)
        {   
            // Sql Sorgusunu Çalıştır Sonucu resulta At
            $this->result =   $this->CI->db->query($sql);
            // Procedure İçin Yazılmış
            while(mysqli_next_result($this->CI->db->conn_id)){
                if($l_result = mysqli_store_result($this->CI->db->conn_id)){
                    mysqli_free_result($l_result);
                }
            }
            // Procedure İçin Yazılmış      
            // Sonucu Döndür
            return $this->result;    
        }   
    } 
?>
```

1 - 2 Query And Result: No Problem

4 - 5 Query And Result:

```
Commands out of sync; you can’t run this command now
```

Do not have an exact result?  for Use

Comment: It's really hard to understand your question, please try to use proper english sentences.

Comment: mmmh ya... not better...

Answer (score 0):

Why not just return the CI result object?

```
$this->result = $this->CI->db->query($sql, TRUE)->result();
```

...Rather than using your while loop?  CI probably already ran the loop, and all the results have been freed anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Check out this thread:

[Calling stored procedure in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767231/calling-stored-procedure-in-codeigniter?rq=1)

You need to modify the mysqli_result.php file.