# How to use two or more stored procedures in codeigniter code?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, stored-procedures

I'm working on `Codeigniter` project and I'm using a `stored procedures` for my back-end operations. When I'm using a single `stored procedure` for `SELECT` statement, it will work fine. But when I'm trying to call two or more `stored procedures` for same operation it gives me an error.

**ERROR:**

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 2014
>
> Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
>
> call all_Cluster()
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/prop/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

Here is my code:

Model:

```
public function getProperty()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query('call select_prop_SP()');
        // if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
        $query->next_result(); 
        $query->free_result();
    }
public function area()
    {
         $query = $this->db->query('call select_area_SP()');
        // if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
        $query->next_result(); 
        $query->free_result();
    }
public function cluster()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query('call select_Cluster_SP()');
        // if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
        $query->next_result(); 
        $query->free_result();
    }
```

Here is my SP:

select_area_SP

```
BEGIN
SELECT `area_id`, `area_name`, `area_status` FROM `tbl_area`;
END
```

select_Cluster_SP

```
BEGIN
SELECT `cluster_id`, `cluster_name`, `area_id`, `cluster_status` FROM `tbl_cluster`;
END
```

I've googled it for long time but I haven't gate any positive result.
I've gone through [Calling stored procedure in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767231/calling-stored-procedure-in-codeigniter)
and make all changes, but no success.

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commands-out-of-sync.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `next_result` and `free_result` functions are not executing because the `return` sentence exits function. You must store the result in a temporary variable before return:

```
public function cluster()
{
        $query = $this->db->query('call select_Cluster_SP()');
        $result = $query->result();
        $query->next_result(); 
        $query->free_result();
        return $result;
}
```

OR change your configuration to `mysqli` driver that includes the next_result function after every stored procedure call:

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```

Comment: Looks like it is giving an error `Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_result::next_result()`